# Resource leak: workbook is never closed warning when using Apache.POI XSSFWorkbook

Tags: java, garbage-collection, apache-poi

So, I using Apache POI in order to parse an Excel file to my Database. For this I am initializing an `XSSFWorkbook` as follows:

```
XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(fIP);
```

Then I proceed with my method. `workbook.close()` is not available as a method to close the workbook afterwards. Any ideas of how can I let garbage collection take the workbook after the task is finished?

Comment: [Workbook.close()](http://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/Workbook.html#close%28%29) is very much available, why aren't you using that?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I had this issue, and it was making little sense.
In the end I tracked the issue down to my IDE (netbeans) was picking up an earlier version of the POI libraries (v3.8) which didn't have the "close" method.
So check your class path and look for duplicate imports of different versions of the POI libraries.

Comment: Incredible but true! Same thing happened to me. I don't understand how the compiler do not take advice of this?

Answer (score 9):

The [docs](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/xssf/usermodel/XSSFWorkbook.html) say that the class implements `Closeable`. Thus it has a `close()` method and you can close the workbook like this:

```
XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(fIP)

// Do your stuff;

workbook.close();
```

Since the class also implements `AutoCloseable` youn can go with a try-with-resources block as well:

```
try (XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(fIP)) {
    // Do your stuff
}
```

If you use this approach the workbook will be closed automatically after the try block has finished.

Answer (score 1):

Just change the example from apache page of:

```
try {
    FileInputStream excelFile = new FileInputStream(new File(FILE_NAME));
    Workbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(excelFile);
    //more stuffs
}
```

To:

```
Workbook workbook;
try {
    InputStream excelFile = file.getInputStream();
    workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(excelFile);
    //more stuffs

    workbook.close();
    excelFile.close();
}
```

Comment: Why should one do that??