# cannot find symbol Workbook.close()

Tags: java, apache-poi, xssf

I saw multiple questions with this header but didn't get my answer.

```
 private void createHandBackFile(XSSFSheet sheet, String programId, XSSFWorkbook workbook) throws IOException {
    String output = "C:\\Users\\muddassirr\\Downloads\\Personal\\STORE\\Output";

    File file = new File(output + File.separator + programId);
    if (!file.exists()) {
        file.mkdirs();
    }
    int noOfColumns = sheet.getRow(0).getPhysicalNumberOfCells();
    for(int i = 0; i < noOfColumns; i++) {
        sheet.autoSizeColumn(i);
    }
    FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(new File(output + File.separator + programId + File.separator + "HAND_BACK.xlsx"));
    workbook.write(outputStream);
    outputStream.close();
    workbook.close();
}
```

There is no compilation error. But As I run I get runtime error saying

```
java: cannot find symbol
symbol:   method close()
location: variable workbook of type org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook
```

Comment: `cannot find symbol` must be a compilation error. Isn't it?

Comment: Which version of POI are you using?

Comment: possible dup of https://stackoverflow.com/a/33802626/3694269

Comment: Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/34283033/4405757

Comment: @user7 its runtime error

Comment: @user7 3.17 version I am using

Comment: Check your class path and look for duplicate imports of different versions of the POI libraries. [This is not allowed.](https://poi.apache.org/faq.html#faq-N10204)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I got the answer. This dependency was missing in pom.xml

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.poi/poi-ooxml -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
        <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
        <version>3.17</version>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: @AxelRichter actually I had changed to 3.17.